# Want to make a automatic value distributor

Tags: google-sheets

I'm making a character sheet for an RPG, and I was thinking about doing it in a way that when you choose an origin for your character, the points go to the right attributes.

For example, if I select the investigator class, I get +5 points in the investigation and perception of attributes. In short, I want to automate the process of placing points in the right places.

I tried with some combinations like `=IF(VLOOKUP))` and others that I can't remember. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or the references that I searched for wasn't related with what I want.

In case that someone is curious about the sheet [here's the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-a6kequBW40BIRyCnJWkcCEGFTTHNxrsjZh9wDAnqBY/edit?usp=sharing), and if I wasn't clear in some parts, sorry, my English is not the best.

Comment: `In case that someone is curious about the sheet` Hi. Yes we are interested in youir data but, as the `google-sheets` tag notes **`Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.`** Your question needs to stand on its own, and ALL the relevant information needs to be included in the body of the question. Please don't expect that users must/will/can/should open your spreadsheet in order to get a better understanding of your question. Would you please edit your question to include this information.